# MySQL and getting each players' status on their last match

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL database. There are matches which are played by 1 player vs. 1 players. In other words, 2 players per match. Each player can be only once on every match. It is also possible that a player is not playing all matches.

I also would like to find the last match where each player has played and get player's status on that match as `end_status`. This is not working.

In other words, if a player is player 1 on his last match, I would like to get `end_status_player1.status` as `end_status`. But if a player is player 2 on his last match, in that case `end_status_player2.status` should be used as `end_status`.

```
SELECT (end_status_player1.status, end_status_player2.status) AS end_status
FROM players
INNER JOIN teams ON teams.id = players.team_id /* OK */

/* if this is player's last match and he is player 1, this should be used */

LEFT JOIN matches AS player1 ON player1.chart_id = players.comp_id
                           AND player1.player1_id = players.id
LEFT JOIN status AS end_status_player1 ON end_status_player1.id = player1.user_status_id

/* if this is player's last match and he is player 2, this should be used */

LEFT JOIN matches AS player2 ON player2.chart_id = players.comp_id
                           AND player2.player2_id = players.id
LEFT JOIN status AS end_status_player2 ON end_status_player2.id = player2.user_status_id

WHERE players.comp_id = 107
GROUP BY teams.id
```

Comment: I don't understand the parenthesis

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry I modfied my question. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Maybe, but I've said my peace